# Django TemplateDoesNotExist admin/login.html

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am working with django 1.4. And this error appeared:

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
admin/login.html**

I tried to reinstall django, but i did not work... Please Help!

Comment: You need to shere your settings.py file, Template root config.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add the admin tempates path name to TEMPLATES['DIRS'] in your django settings.py

The default TEMPLATES:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

change to if you are using Django project created by Pycharm:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'venv/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Django by default looks for templates in each app having directory name "templates".
you can add your own path in settings.py file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to use the default Django admin, be sure that `'django.contrib.admin'` is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error trying to use the default built-in login functionality.

My settings.py has the default settings, 'django.contrib.admin' is in the INSTALLED_APPS section of my settings.py file, as suggested by sean.

Elaborating on Tim's answer, I believe that we are refering to a missing template.

See the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login:
"It’s your responsibility to provide the html for the login template, called registration/login.html by default."

Answer (score 0):

Add your app name in `INSTALLED_APPS` list inside `settings.py`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting a "TemplateDoesNotExist" error, that means you are referring to a template that does not exist. :) You should have a templates directory, and check to see if admin/login.html exists in that directory path.

[This is the Django 1.4 template documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/) IMO the Django documentation is quite good compared to most stock documentation.

Also you should know that the admin interface is not really designed to be customized. The built-in admin interface has a login feature already built-in, if you create a superuser with the manage.py script. If you're trying to build your own template, you should do so separate from the admin interface, unless you disable/remove the built-in admin interface completely and design your own from scratch. Modifying built-in admin code is more trouble than it's worth in my opinion.